# Why is A a subset of P(A) only when A = nil?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For example, if $A = \{1,2\}$ then $P(A) = \{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$

But then isn't $A \subseteq P(A)$ since all the elements that are in $A$ are also in $P(A)$?

Comment: $P(A)=\{\{\varnothing\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$, to be precise. So $A\in P(A)$

Comment: The inclusion $A\subset P(A)$ is only true for the $\emptyset$ by the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#2._Axiom_of_regularity_.28also_called_the_Axiom_of_foundation.29). This states that for every non-empty set $A$, there is an element $y\in A$ such that $y\cap A=\emptyset$. If $A\subset P(A)$ then $y\in P(A)$ and therefore $y\cap A=y$. Contradiction. Finally, clearly $A=\emptyset \subset P(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** Not all of the elements in $A$ are in $P(A)$. Your error here is that you are assuming that $\{1\}$ means the same thing as $1$ and likewise for $2$, but that isn't true. $\{1\}$ represents the set with the number $1$ as its only element, and $1$ is the first natural number. It is true that
$$1\in \{1\}$$
But not
$$1\in \{\{1\}\}$$

However, you could say that
$$A\in P(A)$$

Comment: The best answer to the question "what is mathematics" ive heard is "the study of objects"... when doing anything its always worth asking "what type of objects am i working with" which is the above answer clarifies greatly

Comment: @Vaas I'm glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 3):

No. $A$ is not a subset of $P(A)$, because $1 \in A$ but $1 \not\in P(A)$. We do have $\{1\} \in P(A)$, but that is something different than $1 \in P(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A \subseteq P(A)$ means every element in $A$ is also in $P(A)$. In your example, for example, $1$ is not an element of $P(A)$ because $P(A)$ is a group that contains groups and $1$ is not a group. $\{1\}$, however, is a group.

Comment: So if I had a family of sets, say F, and F = {{1}, {2}}, will F be a subset of P(A)?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \subseteq P(A)$. Suppose $A \neq  \emptyset$, then by [Axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity),

$$\exists x \in A\text{ such that }x \cap A=\emptyset$$

As $A \subseteq P(A)$, therefore $$x \in P(A)$$ Also, $$\{x\} \in P(A)$$

Now, $x \in P(A)$ implies that $x \subseteq A$. Thus, $$x=x\cap A=\emptyset$$
Hence, $\emptyset \in A.$

Hence, we obtain the following $$A \subseteq P(A) \implies A=\emptyset \text{ or }\emptyset \in A$$